# How to fast fill with data one poco model from other model

Tags: c#, .net, resharper, poco

Does anybody know tools (may be resharper or any another tool) or some techniques for fast filling POCO objects with data from any another object? I mean the best way to get something like that:

```
var some_object = new FirstModel {
    Property1 = second_model.Property1,
    Property2 = second_model.Property2,
    Property3 = second_model.Property3,
    //...etc.
}
```

Comment: Do you need the automation to happen runtime, or in the IDE (since you mentioned ReSharper)?

Comment: I mean IDE. Something that will generate a code like above in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

From your question it is not quite clear whether you want help in the IDE to auto-generate the code you have shown, or you want object-object mapping.

AutoMapper will certainly help you if you want the latter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AutoMapper for this:

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper